# Getting a 403: restricted_client when trying to login with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code:

```
const config = {
    // config info here
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

I'm able to have the pop up screen for Google oAuth appear, but when selecting my account to log in I get the following error:

[image]

I have googled and tripled checked that there's a support email. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. The Firebase settings are pretty straightforward so I'm pretty confused. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Cloud Console: http://console.cloud.google.com

Select the project you are using.

In the left side menu, go go "APIs & Services" -> "OAuth Consent screen"

Populate the missing data, especially the support email.

Save your changes.

Comment: This solution didn't work for Google provider auth :(. I still having the same problem with gmail login with the facebook's browser, works fine for the rest (safari, chrome, firefox, etc).